# VS 2010: TFS throws pathLength exceeded on ALL files even though path length is less than 260

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, tfs

I have an infuriating problem that occurred recently.

Whenever I try to add or rename a file in any of the projects in my solution, or even the solution name itself, I get the following:

```
Error
TF10210: Source control encountered an error during move
operation: Unable to rename 
C:\xxxxxxxxvisualstudio.com\xxxxxxxx -
Rigg\src\xxxxxxxx.Rigg.Domain\Area.cs to
C:\xxxxxxxxvisualstudio.com\xxxxxxxx -
Rigg\src\xxxxxxxx.Rigg.Domain\Area2.cs
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: pathLength
```

(I've replaced the names of mine and the client's company with x'es.)

The thing is, up to last Friday I never had this problem, I've been working on the solution for more than 6 months. 
I have not renamed or restructured the solution folder recently.

I've tried deleting the solution folder and getting an earlier checkin from before this happened, with no luck.

I do not get the message if I open the solution in VS2013, which leads me to believe the problem is related to VS2010, and maybe doesn't have anything to do with path length. Unfortunately I can't work on the project in VS2013, as it is MVC3.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Solved. I changed the solution's mapping, and it worked. Then I changed it back to the original, and it still worked! I have no idea why this happened, but apparently fiddling with the mapping solved it.

Comment: You can try to remap the solution's folder to a shorter local folder.

Comment: Same problem here. VS2010, TFS Online. Removing, changing, and re-mapping didn't fix it - still can't add new files/folders to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have Dynamics AX 2013 R3 CU8 with the same error:
Team Foundation Server nonfatal error
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: pathLength

Can you please describe a bit more detailed how you have fixed the error?

Comment: I have the same issue using VS studio 2010 SP1 with the integration SP.

Comment: I can't check in new files or new project...never had this issue before. Please keep us updated with details?

Answer (score 0):

We inadvertently broke VS2010 compatibility in our latest update. We rolled out a fix over night. Let me know is you still hit it. Sorry for the trouble!